# Gyro measurement to absolute angles

Tags: imu, gyroscope, frame

Let us assume we have a gyro that is perfectly aligned to a global frame ($X,Y,Z$).

From what I know the gyro data give me the angular rate with respect to the gyro axis ($x,y,z$). So let's say I got $\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z$. Since I know that the 2 frames are perfectly aligned I perform the following operations:

- $\theta_X = dt * \omega_x$
- $\theta_Y = dt * \omega_y$
- $\theta_Z = dt * \omega_z$

where $\theta_X$ is the rotation angle around $X$ and so on.

My question is: what is this update like in the following steps? Because this time the measurement that I get are no more directly related to the global frame (rotated with respect to the gyro frame).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step works because it is implied that your frames are "aligned", meaning that:

$$
\theta_{X_0} = 0 \\
\theta_{Y_0} = 0 \\
\theta_{Z_0} = 0 \\
$$

In general (as with any integration!), you have some starting angles(initial condition), $\theta_{(X,Y,Z)_0}$, and you proceed to update from there, such that:

$$
\theta_{X_N} = \theta_{X_{N-1}} + \omega_{X_N} dT \\
\theta_{Y_N} = \theta_{Y_{N-1}} + \omega_{Y_N} dT \\
\theta_{Z_N} = \theta_{Z_{N-1}} + \omega_{Z_N} dT \\
$$

Note that when your initial conditions are as you use in your example, the $\theta_{N-1}$ terms vanish leaving you with the equations you originally stated.

Comment: That's my actual problem. I would do like you've just shown, but where do I get the angular velocities with respect to the global frame (i.e. $\omega_X$)? Because from the gyro I only get $\omega_x$ (with respect to the gyro frame) and so on.

Comment: @charles - that's covered with your [other question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8247/9720) regarding transforming angular velocities from one frame to another, where my answer is: just use a regular 4x4 transform. If you have questions/comments on this please go to your other question and update the question text or add comments to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that was clarifying. But the thing is: assuming we have the 3 current angles and we want to find the rotation matrix R. How should I do? I thought about RPY, is that correct? And in case, why the rotation composition is in this exact sequence and not PRY for example? Thank you again

Comment: @charles - Finding the rotation matrix $R$ *is* hard because, as you mention, multiplication order matters. This is why some people might prefer to use [unit quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) for rotation instead. This question of "why order matters" is more complicated than can be answered in a comment, but you could read more [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/788951/240336) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Sequential_angles), but, basically, order matters because it changes your point of reference for the next rotation.